# Can I slow down Django

Tags: django, http

Simple question really

```
./manage.py runserver
```

Can I slow down `localhost:8000` on my development machine so I can simulate file uploads and work on the look and feel of ajax uploading?

Comment: Run it in a virtualised environment which allows you to control speed of execution?

Comment: You could upload larger files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

depending on where you want to simulate such you could simply sleep?

```
from time import sleep
sleep(500)
```

Comment: This is my favorite way to test HttpRequest timeouts on the client-side of things.

Comment: Just a warning, the parameter for sleep is in seconds. So 500 is veeery slow :D

Comment: But, can you do it in all views?

Answer (score 8):

On osx or freebds, you can use `ipfw` to limit bandwidth on specific ports:

```
  sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 1Bytes/s delay 100ms
  sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 8000
```

Do not forget to delete it when you do not need it anymore:

```
sudo ipfw delete 1
```

[Credit: jaguarcy](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080119112509736)

For osx there is also free app that will allow this:

http://slowyapp.com/

Comment: I love this method in general to test page loads for slower visitors. DOM processing looks very different when elements are constantly loading... !

Comment: So if I am testing a webpage on my Mac from `localhost` Django server on the same, this will simulate a delayed page-load?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a [customized upload handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/file-uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers) or subclass current upload handler to mainly slow down [`receive_data_chunk()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadhandler.py#L172) method in it. Or set a pdb breakpoint inside `receive_data_chunk()` and manually proceed the uploading. Or even simpler, try to upload some large file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the Charles HTTP Proxy.  It lets you throttle the connection and can simulate all sorts of network conditions.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use the slow file upload handler from django-gubbins:

```
import time
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import FileUploadHandler

class SlowFileUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler):
    """
    This is an implementation of the Django file upload handler which will
    sleep between processing chunks in order to simulate a slow upload. This
    is intended for development when creating features such as an AJAXy
    file upload progress bar, as uploading to a local process is often too
    quick.
    """
    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        time.sleep(2)
        return raw_data

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        return None
```

You can either enable this globally, by adding it to:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
    "myapp.files.SlowFileUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",
)
```

Or enable it for a specific request:

```
request.upload_handlers.insert(0, SlowFileUploadHandler())
```

Make sure the request is excepted from CSRF checking, as mentioned at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#id1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slow things down across all requests a very easy way to go would be to use ngrok https://ngrok.com/ . Use the ngrok url for requests then connect to a vpn in another country. That will make your requests really slow.

Comment: I like ngrok. Its awsome