# Django: how to emulate a slow server?

Tags: python, django, database, http, server

The production server my work is pushed to performs significantly worse than my local development environment, where everything runs fast and smoothly, so I cannot figure out if any change I make may or may not have a bad performance in production.

In that server, responses take a lot of time, mostly I assume because of the database queries, rather than the server's processing power and memory capacity.

I wonder if there is any way to set up a server configuration to emulate these bad conditions: how can I reduce the power of my local Django server so that responses take longer, processing power is low and, most importantly, database connection is slow?

I hope this is not a crazy ask, but it is something I really need to figure out how my code will behave in production, since I have no way of telling that from my local environment.

Comment: If you believe its your database, you could try locating your slowest queries; [postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92071/get-statistics-of-slow-running-queries) or [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: @castis It is not **my** database, it's production's, and I have no access or control over it.

Comment: You could just time how long a query takes to return a bunch of times, get average and then put a sleep in your version to simulate the delay.

Comment: @Jacobr365 sure I could do that, but I would have to do that for every single query I make, which would be tremendous work. If I could emulate a slow server and pinpoint what part of the request or what query is slow, rather than having to check single handedly every one of them and every piece of new code.

Comment: How are you interacting with the db, using django models or hitting it with raw sql?

Comment: @Jacobr365 Django models

Comment: Alright, so as far as I know, your best bet is to find where the slowdown occurs, time it, and simulate the slowdown with sleep in your dev env. There is likely some way you could mimic the slowdown by working in a virtual environment by controlling resources.

Answer (score 2):

As some comments suggest above, you could slow down the dev server by doing what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10300825/1138710) suggests.

If you suspect the database, you could change the `QuerySet` methods in `db/models/query.py` in the django code and add something like this:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(0.5)  # this is seconds, not milliseconds ;)
```

but this is all guesses.

You could setup something like [opbeat](https://opbeat.com/django/) in your code to get actual production info about your code, so you can work out what the problem really is (and speed up production instead of slowing down dev!).

For your local dev environment, you could also try [django-silk](https://github.com/django-silk/silk) to get a sense of how many queries your code runs.